# The scope of NSTimer()

Tags: swift, nstimer

**My problem:  NSTimer() declared in one function influences the other one.**

I'm making a simple, rpg game that allows two players to fight against each other. The game has a text field, which displays **one-second** messages, for example "Player one attacks" etc. After the game is finished the text field is supposed to print the winner and leave the message in the text field.  To tackle the first part (show a message, after one second show an empty string) I made the following code:

```
    func printEmpty() {
    textToDisplayLabel.text = ""
}
    func announcer(player: Character) {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    textToDisplayLabel.text = "\(player.name) attacks"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "printEmpty", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
```

To tackle the second part (show the info about the winner and leave it in the text field) I used:

```
    func hideAfterAPlayerHasWon(winner: Character) {
    leftPlayerAttackButton.hidden = true
    rightPlayerAttackButton.hidden = true
    leftPlayerHpLabel.hidden = true
    rightPlayerHpLabel.hidden = true
    leftPlayerNameLabel.hidden = true
    rightPlayerNameLabel.hidden = true

    if winner.side == Character.playerSide.left {
        soldierMain.hidden = true
        let centerXConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: orcMain, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        let centerYConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: orcMain, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        self.view.addConstraint(centerXConst)
        self.view.addConstraint(centerYConst)
        textToDisplayLabel.text = "\(leftPlayer.name) has won"

    } else {
        orcMain.hidden = true
        let centerXConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: soldierMain, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        let centerYConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: soldierMain, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        self.view.addConstraint(centerXConst)
        self.view.addConstraint(centerYConst)
        textToDisplayLabel.text = "\(rightPlayer.name) has won"
    }
```

}

The problem is that when the game starts, the info about actions, for example "player attacks" etc. are displayed and they hide after one second as I want them to do, but the info about the winner behaves like these about actions even thought the timer was only declared in announcer function. So the question occured to me: what's the scope of NSTimer() and how should I solve this problem?

EDIT: Here's the function where announcer is called (as well as hideAfter...)

```
@IBAction func onLeftPlayerAttackPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if leftPlayer.type == Character.charType.orc {
        playOrcSlash()
    }
    if leftPlayer.type == Character.charType.soldier {
        playSoldierSlash()
    }
    announcer(leftPlayer)
    updateHp(leftPlayer, defender: rightPlayer)
    disableButton(leftPlayerAttackButton)
    if !(rightPlayer.isAlive) {
        hideAfterAPlayerHasWon(leftPlayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where do you call your function `announcer(player: Character)` ?

Comment: I edited the post and added this info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> what's the scope of NSTimer()

It doesn't have a "scope". Once you've scheduled it, it belongs to the NSRunLoop which owns it and is responsible for firing it. If it's a nonrepeating timer, it goes out of existence after it has fired.

That has nothing to do with your problem. You have an elementary logic mistake:

1. `onLeftPlayerAttackPressed` sets up the timer (`announcer(leftPlayer)`) and calls `hideAfterAPlayerHasWon`.
2. Then `hideAfterAPlayerHasWon` puts "player has won" in the label.
3. Then the timer fires and empties the label again!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your timer fires after your label is updated, what you can do :

Delay the call to your function `hideAfterAPlayerHasWon` by one or two second so you are sure that your timer has already fired.

```
if !(rightPlayer.isAlive) {
  let yourDelayTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * NUMBER_SECOND_DELAY)
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, yourDelayTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   self.hideAfterAPlayerHasWon(leftPlayer)
  })  
}
```